# Disable line correction in LibraOffice Draw's FreeForm line

Tags: linux-mint, libreoffice, drawing, libreoffice-draw

I am using LibreOffice Draw's FreeForm line in order to achieve pencil-like drawing abilities in LibreOffice draw. I tried it and the main problem with it is that it doesn't draw exactly what I draw in practice, but a "normalized" or "corrected" version of it.
Attached are screenshots of what I draw vs. what actually appears:

If I try to draw this

[image: "sharp-edged" shape]

I get this

[image: "rounded" shape]

(this is just an example, the "line correction" does many other things)

In any case, I have a graphical drawing tablet so I don't need this "line correction" functionality on the freeform line, and it is getting in the way. Is there any way to disable that? Or even another tool within LibreOffice Draw that implements that?

I am using Linux Mint and am using LibreOffice draw version 6.4.7.2.

Comment: This is a follow-up question of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/683814/free-sketching-on-libreoffice-draw.

Answer (score 0):

The answer at https://askubuntu.com/questions/606440/how-can-i-draw-freely-with-libreoffice-draw recommends using Inkscape and then importing into Draw.